# How to Set the SiteMapNode Title Dynamically from Master Page ? ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, sitemap, sitemapnode

In My Web.sitemap I have the following:

```
<siteMapNode url="~/Groups/ViewGroups.aspx" urlRoute="groups/{PostId}/{PostTitle}" />
</siteMapNode>
```

In my MasterPage I have implemented the **ItemDataBound** event to try and set the title of each page that implements the master page dynamically but for some reason the title is not being set.

```
protected void SiteMapPath1_ItemDataBound(object sender, SiteMapNodeItemEventArgs e)
{
    string CurrentNodeTitle = GetTitleFromDatabase();

    if (e.Item.ItemType == SiteMapNodeItemType.Current) {
         e.Item.SiteMapNode.Title = CurrentNodeTitle;
    }
}
```

If I set the title in the  then it works perfectly but when I set it using **e.Item.SiteMapNode.Title = CurrentNodeTitle;** the title is nto being set.

Comment: Try the `ItemCreated` event. `ItemDataBound` is not intended to use from your code.

Comment: @Amiram Korach Thanks for the suggestion, I've implemented the ItemCreated event but it still did not work the title is not being applied.

Comment: Is this the correct way to Dynamically set the Title of a SiteMap?

Answer (score 0):

In the Web.sitemap you must have in the Title someting like % vble %, If this value is a literal, no changes will applied